# What is the Best Way to Perform Geo Spatial Searches with Entity Framework Code First CTP 5?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, data-access, ef-code-first

I'd really like to give Entity Framework 4 Code First CTP a try with a greenfield app but I want to make sure that geo spatial searches will not be a problem before I do, or I'll go another route.

Has anyone performed a geo-spatial search with EF CF? If so, how did you do it and why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a problem insofar as it's not supported in L2E. But you can write a proc which returns the right results, and consume that with L2E.

I think [NerdDinner has an example of this](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExtendingNerdDinnerExploringDifferentDatabaseOptions.aspx).

Edited to add: You can also use straight SQL in EF 4 without a proc.

Comment: I was afraid that this would be the answer. I couldn't find anything to suggest that this was possible. Going to stick with Nhib until they refine EF CF. Thanks.